# Async method not waiting for await, returns undefined instead

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

We're currently digitizing a planning poker game.
When all users submitted their vote, it should check if the majority of users submitted a coffee card, which has a value of -1.

The methods retrieves everyones votes from a Mongo database like so:

```
async checkCoffeeTimeout()
    {
        let coffeeVotes = 0;
        // Get the votes from the database
        await this.updateDBData()
            .then(response => {
                this.dbData = response[0];
                let feature = this.dbData.features[this.featurePointer];
                let half    = 1;

                if(feature !== undefined) // Waiting state has no features yet
                {
                    half = feature.votes.length / 2
                    feature.votes.forEach(vote => vote.value == -1 ? coffeeVotes++ : '');
                }

                return coffeeVotes >= half;
            });
}
```

For some reason the method won't await the promise **this.updateDBData()**, which is:

```
    updateDBData()
    {
        return SessionObject.find({_id: this.dbData._id})
    }
```

Calling the checkCoffeeTimeout() in an async method, prepended by an await still returns undefined.

Am i missing something? I'm quite new to the await/async way of promises

Comment: `SessionObject.find({_id: this.dbData._id})` should return a promise that will be *awaited* for.  And you don't need to apply `then` since you are using async/await.

Comment: `checkCoffeeTimeout` does not return anything. The callback to `then` returns something, but that doesn't go anywhere. Don't mix `await` and `then`, use one or the other (prefer `await`).

Comment: Oh now i see, thanks!